# TypeError: this.posts.filter is not a function using Vue js and wordpress api

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js

I'm trying to fetch some posts in wordpress using the formidable pro api and vue js. The data loads correctly initially, however, I get TypeError: this.posts.filter is not a function when I click on a category or type something in the input field.

In the filteredPost function I'm always getting undefined from console.log("posts", this.posts[0]).

JS

```
var postList = Vue.extend({

    template: "#post-list-template",

    data: function(){
        return {
            posts:'',
            nameFilter:'',
            categories: '',
            categoryFilter: ''
        }
    },

    mounted: function(){

        var apiKey = 'my-api-key';

        this.$http.get('/wp-json/frm/v2/forms/10/entries', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Basic '+ btoa( apiKey +':x' )
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
              this.posts = response.data;
            })

        //all category data

        this.$http.get('/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/')
            .then(response => this.categories = response.data);   
    },

    computed: {
        filteredPost: function () {

            var self = this;

            var selectedCategory = self.categoryFilter;

            console.log("selectedCategory", selectedCategory)
            console.log("posts", this.posts[0])

            if( selectedCategory === ""){

                return this.posts;

            }else{

                return this.posts.filter(function(post) {

                    return post.sqaja-value.indexOf(selectedCategory) >= 0;

                });

            }

            if( this.nameFilter == ''){
                return this.posts;
            }       

            var lowerCaseFilter = this.nameFilter.toLowerCase()

            return this.posts.filter(function(post){
                return post.meta.bl3pl.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowerCaseFilter) >= 0;

            });



        },

    } //computed
})

// Start a new instance of router (instead of router.map)
var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: postList }
  ]
})


// Start a new instance of the Application required (instead of router.start)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  template: '<router-view></router-view>'
})
```

Template

```
<main class="wrap">
        <div id="app">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </main>

    <template id="post-list-template">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h4>Filter by Title:&nbsp;</h4>
                    <input type="text" name="" v-model="nameFilter">

                    <h4>Filter by category</h4>
                    <div class="radio-wrap">
                        <input type="radio" value="" v-model="categoryFilter">
                        <label> All </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="radio-wrap" v-for="category in categories" v-if="category.name != 'Uncategorized'">
                        <input type="radio" v-bind:value="category.id" v-model="categoryFilter">
                        <label> {{ category.name }} </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4" v-for="post in filteredPost">
                        <div class="card post">
                            <img class="card-img-top" v-bind:src="post.meta.xbxiv" >
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h2 class="card-text">{{ post.meta.bl3pl }}</h2>
                                <small class="tags" v-for="category in post.cats">{{ category.name }}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- .post -->
                    </div> <!-- .col-md-4 -->
                </div> <!-- .row -->
            </div> <!-- .container -->
        </div> <!-- .wrapper -->
    </template>
```

EDIT
I dont know if this is relevant or not but the code works with the standard wp api

```
[
    {
        "id": 15577,
        "date": "2018-09-10T23:30:43",
        "date_gmt": "2018-09-10T18:00:43",
        "guid": {
        "rendered": "https://example.com/?p=15577"
        },
        "modified": "2018-09-11T10:17:59",
        "modified_gmt": "2018-09-11T04:47:59",
        "slug": "demonetisation-and-its-impact-on-tax-collection-and-formalisation-of-the-economy",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "post",
        "link": "https://example.com/demonetisation-and-its-impact-on-tax-collection-and-formalisation-of-the-economy/",
        "title": {
        "rendered": "Demonetisation and its impact on Tax collection and Formalisation of the Economy"
        },
        "content": {},
        "excerpt": {},
        "author": 6,
        "featured_media": 15576,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "ping_status": "open",
        "sticky": false,
        "template": "",
        "format": "standard",
        "meta": [],
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "_links": {}
    }
]
```

However, the formidable api looks like this

```
{
    "y8rau": {
        "id": "5352",
        "item_key": "y8rau",
        "name": "",
        "ip": "::1",
        "meta": {},
        "form_id": "10",
        "post_id": "4862",
        "user_id": "1",
        "parent_item_id": "0",
        "is_draft": "0",
        "updated_by": "1",
        "created_at": "2016-11-25 02:46:33",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-21 10:08:58"
    },
    "o0nqn": {
        "id": "5353",
        "item_key": "o0nqn",
        "name": "",
        "ip": "::1",
        "meta": {},
        "form_id": "10",
        "post_id": "4863",
        "user_id": "1",
        "parent_item_id": "0",
        "is_draft": "0",
        "updated_by": "1",
        "created_at": "2016-11-25 02:46:34",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-21 09:41:57"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you console.log the response.data when you try to assign this.posts in mounted.

Comment: Yes, i can see the data in my console. i've added an edit. can you please take a look and see if that helps in resolving this? Thank you for your time

Comment: what if you try `console.log("posts", self.posts[0])` in your computed filteredPosts  function?

Comment: Thats giving me "undefined"

Answer (score 3):

That is because you have declared your `posts` as an empty string during initialisation. A string prototype does not have a `filter` method, hence the error.

If you declare it as an empty array at first, the error should go away:

```
data: function(){
    return {
        posts: [],
        nameFilter: '',
        categories: [],
        categoryFilter: ''
    }
},
```

p/s: I suppose `categories` should be an array, too.

Comment: Still getting the same error: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.posts.filter is not a function"

Comment: Hi, i've added an edit. can you please take a look and see if that helps in resolving this? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are getting a response to your http request but it is not assigning that response to "posts". This is probably due to how the life cycle hooks of vue work. It may work if you change `mounted()` to `created()` but you could also make 'posts' a computed property rather than a data element.

To do this remove posts (and categories) from "data", so you'll be left with this.

```
data: function(){
  return {
    nameFilter:'',
    categoryFilter: ''
  }
},
```

then make posts (and categories) a computed function:

```
computed: {
  posts() {
    //put your $http.get request in here, but instead of assigning the response, return it
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    })
  },
  categories() {
    //separate $http.get for categories and return response
  }
  // Then your other computed properties like filteredPosts
...
}
```

You can access posts in other computed functions with `this.posts`